# How to test getCookie function with Jasmine and PhantomJS

Tags: unit-testing, cookies, jasmine, phantomjs

I have a function on the window object like so:

```
window.getCookie = function(name){
   // Get cookie with name, uses document.cookie for this.
};
```

Now I want to test this logic in my unit tests for which I'm using Jasmine and PhantomJS. The test looks like:

```
it('should get a cookie with a specific name.', function () {
    // Setup
    document.cookie = 'Foo=Bar; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC';

    // Execute
    var result = window.getCookie('Foo');

    // Test
    expect(result).toBe('Bar');
});
```

The thing is that it turns out that document.cookie is always '' when the code is executed within PhantomJS. So setting the cookie on line 1 is basically not doing anything. If you log it on line 2, the value is ''.

How do I get around this?

Comment: I eventually worked around it by using my own variable instead of document.cookie. In the real world I set that variable to be equal to document.cookie and in my test I can override it. It's kind of dirty so I'm still open to suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

mmm, it's strange that document.cookie is '' using PhantomJs only. Usually, when cookie has an expired time it is no more available in document.cookie.

Comment: Please, don't use answer as comment